# update xml element value and update certain tags

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, lxml

i have xml with namespace, where i am able to get the value of element. 
i want to update the value with different text. however i want to update the XML based on the `<vlid>` tag value. if this vlid value does not match , then only program should iterate over next `vlink` tag and look for matching text.

I am able to match the `vlid`. i am able to update the XML, however in my case values are updated in all `link` tags, irrespective of `vlid` value.

My problem is i have two Tag starting with `link` having same element list inside and using xpath does recursive search hence finds both element in tag. i am not able to figure how to restrict it to single element.

here is XML file

```
<vtest
    xmlns="test:file">
    <lsm>
        <m-id>v1</m-id>
        <name>v1</name>
        <communication>bi</communication>
        <link>
            <vlid>text</vlid>
            <idx>text</idx>
            <type>text</type>   
            <link>text</link>
            <vl-p>
                <Type>text</Type>
                <n-type>text</n-type>
                <n-id>text</n-id>
                <k-name>text</k-name>
                <k-id>text</k-id>
                <t-name>text</t-name>
                <l-work>text</l-work>
                <t-id>text</t-id>
                <is-required>text</is-required>
            </vl-p>
        </link>
        <link>
            <vlid>text</vlid>
            <idx>text</idx>
            <type>text</type>
            <link>text</link>
            <vl-p>
                <Type>text</Type>
                <n-type>text</n-type>
                <n-id>text</n-id>
                <k-name>text</k-name>
                <k-id>text</k-id>
                <t-name>text</t-name>
                <l-work>text</l-work>
                <t-id>text</t-id>
                <is-required>text</is-required>
            </vl-p>
        </link>
    </lsm>
</vtest>
```

here is my code

```
def update_ld(root, ns, k-name, t-name, n-id, t-id, Type, type):
    """ Update VLDs with Openstack Values.! """
    for vld_list in root.xpath('.//ns:type', namespaces=ns):
        vld_list.text = type
    for vld_list in root.xpath('.//ns:Type', namespaces=ns):
        vld_list.text = Type
    for vld_list in root.xpath('.//ns:k-name', namespaces=ns):
        vld_list.text = k_name
    for vld_list in root.xpath('.//ns:n-id', namespaces=ns):
        vld_list.text = n_id
    for vld_list in root.xpath('.//ns:t-name', namespaces=ns):
        vld_list.text = t_name
    for vld_list in root.xpath('.//ns:t-id', namespaces=ns):
        vld_list.text = t_id
etree.ElementTree(root).write(xmlfile, pretty_print='True')
```

Comment: how do you call your function `update_ld` with the root of the xml, or with an element you have selected first ?

Comment: @PRMoureu: I am calling `update_ld` with root of xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `update_ld` should look like this:

```
def update_ld(element, ns, k-name, t-name, n-id, t-id, Type, type):
    element.xpath('./type').text = type
    element.xpath('./Type').text = Type
    element.xpath('./k_name').text = k_name
    element.xpath('./n_id').text = n_id
    element.xpath('./t_name').text = t_name
    element.xpath('./t_id').text = t_id

# Find all <link> from root
for link in root.xpath('./link'):
    # find all <vl-p> from this <link>
    # Should find only One
    update_ld(link.xpath('./vl-p')[0], ...)
```